# Fundamental mode of Bessel functions (vibration in a circular membrane)

Tags: bessel-functions, wave-equation

How come the fundamental mode of Bessel's equations in solutions of the PDE in the case of the vibrations of circular membrane must be angles independent? (thus making it the axisymmetric case).
So in this particular case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrations_of_a_circular_membrane
-> animations at the bottom of the page are indeed showing that mode $0$'s are angles independent.

I heard it is necessary for $\Theta _0$ (from separation of variables method) to be periodic, but I can't find exactly how we can see that.
Is it a consequence of the initial conditions? How exactly is the link established with mode $0$?

Sincerely,

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific. What equation are you talking about, and where does this equation come from?

Comment: Did my best to make it more specific. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: It does not necessarily need to be angularly independent. But, the periodicity w.r.t $\theta$ is necessary of course, due to geometry. The coordinates $(r,\theta)$ and $(r,\theta+2\pi)$ represent the same physical point, so the solution at those coordinates must be the same. In other words, your solution must be $2\pi$ periodic w.r.t $\theta$.